# Converting timezone aware datetime column to string with UTC time offset

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, strftime, python-polars

I have the following dataframe:

```py
df = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "int": [1, 2, 3],
            "date": ["2010-01-31T23:00:00+00:00","2010-02-01T00:00:00+00:00","2010-02-01T01:00:00+00:00"]
        }
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("date").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
        .dt.with_time_zone("Europe/Amsterdam")
    )
)
```

which gives:

```
┌─────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ int ┆ date                           │
│ --- ┆ ---                            │
│ i64 ┆ datetime[μs, Europe/Amsterdam] │
╞═════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2010-02-01 00:00:00 CET        │
│ 2   ┆ 2010-02-01 01:00:00 CET        │
│ 3   ┆ 2010-02-01 02:00:00 CET        │
└─────┴────────────────────────────────┘
```

I would like to convert this datetime type to a string with a time zone designator, e.g. `2010-02-01 00:00:00+01:00`

I tried the following:

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col("date").dt.strftime(fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"))
```

which gives the following error:

```
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: a formatting trait implementation returned an error: Error
```

My desired output is stated below, which is what you get when you convert a datetime column to a string type in pandas with the `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"` as the format:

```
┌─────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ int ┆ date                     │
│ --- ┆ ---                      │
│ i64 ┆ str                      │
╞═════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2010-02-01 00:00:00+0100 │
│ 2   ┆ 2010-02-01 01:00:00+0100 │
│ 3   ┆ 2010-02-01 02:00:00+0100 │
└─────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

Is there any way to realize this result? Leaving out the `%z` at the end when specifying the format works but the UTC time offset is something I need.

Comment: I think that could be classified as a "bug" and could be reported. As a workaround you could try `.apply(str)` - that seems to give `%:z` instead of `%z` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**py-polars v0.16.3** fixes the issue:

```py
import polars as pl
# pl.version()
# '0.16.3'

df = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "int": [1, 2, 3],
            "date": ["2010-01-31T23:00:00+00:00","2010-02-01T00:00:00+00:00","2010-02-01T01:00:00+00:00"]
        }
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("date").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z") # or fmt="%+"
        .dt.convert_time_zone("Europe/Amsterdam")
    )
)

print(
      df.with_columns(pl.col("date").dt.strftime(fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"))
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ int ┆ date                     │
│ --- ┆ ---                      │
│ i64 ┆ str                      │
╞═════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2010-02-01 00:00:00+0100 │
│ 2   ┆ 2010-02-01 01:00:00+0100 │
│ 3   ┆ 2010-02-01 02:00:00+0100 │
└─────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

Notes

1. to get a colon-separated UTC offset, use `%:z`. See also [Rust / chrono formatting directives](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/format/strftime/).
2. `convert_time_zone` is the new with_time_zone. I hope it stays that way ;-)